# MySQL server taking multiple seconds to run COUNT(*) query using an index on a MyISAM table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database on a shared webhost, which has been running with its application for a couple years.

Today, this simple query:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE id = 123`

Took 16 seconds to run. There is an index on id, the table is MyISAM, and this query usually takes milliseconds. The table has about 1 million rows, and the query should return a COUNT of about 250,000.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows that all the time is being spent `Sending data`. I don't have root access, so no profiling help.

**I have the same database on another server from the same host, and the query executes in 0.06 seconds.**

The host thinks everything is running normally on the server. Is there anything I can point them at?

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE id = 214; 
| 1 | SIMPLE | tickets | ref | id | id | 2 | const | 215307 | Using index |
```

Comment: +1 for actually researching and find your own answer !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to have been that the cardinality of my indices was NULL. I am unsure why the indices would revert to this state when they were apparently fine yesterday.

I discovered this problem by running `SHOW INDEX FROM tickets`.

I ran `ANALYZE TABLE tickets`. Now the EXPLAIN looks subtly different-- the rows have dropped to 1:

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from tickets WHERE id = 214;
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tickets | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 2       | const |    1 | Using index |
```

Comment: +1 for actually researching and find your own answer !!!